# Angular 5 / Material, how to remove vertical scroll in Mat Dialog?

Tags: typescript, angular5, angular-material2

I am trying to remove the vertical scrolling in a Material Dialog.

I was trying with CSS

```
.mat-dialog-container /deep/ {
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

and also with the code in the parent component

```
this.dialog._overlayContainer._containerElement.style.overflowY = "hidden";
```

But, there was no way to do that.

Does it know anyone how I can achive that?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Go to styles.scss file
and then 
add the following:

```
.custom-dialog-container .mat-dialog-container {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

and add

```
panelClass: 'custom-dialog-container'
```

as a part of the MatDialogRef object that you are sending to the dialogComponent

Comment: Good answers should explain _why_, not just add code.

Comment: it works but content is shrinked in bottom with full screen window

Answer (score 10):

In your dialog component's style:

```
/deep/ .mat-dialog-content {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: this is not right solution.

Comment: It was 4 and a half years ago.

Comment: okay cool leave it.

Answer (score 10):

This is my implement. In parent component of `TrendDialogComponent`

```
const dialogRef = this.trendDialog.open(TrendDialogComponent, {
                    autoFocus: false,
                    panelClass: 'trend-dialog',
                    width: '1360px', height: '680px',
                    data: {tagsTrend: this.tagNames}
                  });
```

and add this css to style.css

```
.trend-dialog .mat-dialog-container{
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Inside your dialog component's style, you can use

```
  ::ng-deep .mat-dialog-container {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when my html contains `mat-dialog-content`

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-form-field>
        ....
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Then I changed to,

```
<div>
    <mat-form-field>
        ....
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

And it removes the vertical scroll bar from the dialog.

Answer (score 7):

If your dialog stretches over the whole page and the scrollbar on the right does not disappear, I would suggest this option.

```
.cdk-global-scrollblock {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
::ng-deep .mat-dialog-container {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: What is new in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-dialog-content {
  background-color: #eff2f5;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 -24px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  max-height: 109vh;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30581615)

Answer (score 0):

you can set the css id of your component by thd id of MatDialogConfig

```js
import { Overlay } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
constructor(private overlay: Overlay) {}

let config: MatDialogConfig<BigImgData> = {
    scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.block(),
    id: 'bigImgComp',
};
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(BigImgComponent, config);
```

then set the css of your id in src\styles.css

```css
#bigImgComp {
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */
}
```

Comment: Where exactly does `this.overlay` come from?

Comment: Inject form '@angular/cdk/overlay';

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put this within your local css file.

```
::ng-deep .mat-dialog-container {
  overflow: unset;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

Add your own class to component, here->"myModalComponent" (modal.component.html):

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="myModalContent">
    <img src="{{data.src}}" alt="{{data.alt}}">
</div>
```

and add css to modal.component.scss:

```
.myModalContent {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```